# How can I display month in french inmy apex code?

Tags: date, language

I'm searching to change the display language of my date with it :

```
<apex:outputText value="{0, date, 'le 'dd ' ' MMMM yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!NOW()}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

but i would like display the month in french and not in english.
Ty for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be use of the formula `CASE` and set the month manually depending on the month digit. But it is not a best practice:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!CASE(MONTH(DATEVALUE(NOW())),
                                1, 'Janvier',
                                2, 'Février',
                                3, 'Mars', 
                                4, 'Avril', 
                                5, 'Mai', 
                                6, 'Juin',
                                7, 'Juillet',
                                8, 'Août',
                                9, 'Septembre',
                                10, 'Octobre',
                                11, 'Novembre',
                                12, 'Décembre',
                                '-')}" />
```

You better format the date in Apex, it is much comfortable.

Comment: Ho, ty, i tried this practice but I failed, bad use.
not really the best like you said but it's efficient.
TY

Answer (score 1):

I advise to format the date in Apex. You could do something like the following:

```
// Add those two properties in your Apex controller
private Map<Integer, String> frenchDates = new Map<Integer, String>();
frenchDates.put(1, 'Janvier')
frenchDates.put(2, 'Février')
frenchDates.put(3, 'Mars')
frenchDates.put(4, 'Avril')
frenchDates.put(5, 'Mai')
frenchDates.put(6, 'Juin')
frenchDates.put(7, 'Juillet')
frenchDates.put(8, 'Aout')
frenchDates.put(9, 'Septembre')
frenchDates.put(10, 'Octobre')
frenchDates.put(11, 'Novembre')
frenchDates.put(12, 'Décembre')

private String formattedDate {
    get {
        Datetime dateNow = Datetime.now();
        return String.valueOf(dateNow.day()) + frenchDates.get(dateNow.month()) + String.valueOf(dateNow.year());
    }
    set;
}
```

Then just use formattedDate property directly in your Visualforce page.

Comment: OK thanks,i keep it for later.
TY all

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be taken care of automatically if you just set your language locale to French on your user record.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.
Maybe I failed.